# AngularJS getting JSON data from external URL

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Here is the URL, which in the browser renders as JSON:

http://api.geosvc.com/rest/US/84606/nearby?apikey=4ff687893a7b468cb520b3c4e967c4da&d=20&pt=PostalCode&format=json

Here is what I tried to store the data in a variable:

```
$http.get('http://api.geosvc.com/rest/US/84606/nearby?apikey=4ff687893a7b468cb520b3c4e967c4da&d=20&pt=PostalCode&format=json').then(function(response) {
            $scope.zipCodes = response;
          });
```

Here is the HTML where I tried to display it:

```
<pre>zipCodes {{zipCodes | json}}</pre>
```

But nothing displays, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I also tried this:

```
$http.jsonp('http://api.geosvc.com/rest/US/84606/nearby?apikey=4ff687893a7b468cb520b3c4e967c4da&d=20&pt=PostalCode&format=json').then(function(response) {
                $scope.zipCodes = response;
              });
```

I've also tried AngularJS resource but that is also returning undefined:

```
var zipCodes = $resource("http://api.geosvc.com/rest/US/84606/nearby?apikey=4ff687893a7b468cb520b3c4e967c4da&d=20&pt=PostalCode&format=json",
            { callback: "JSON_CALLBACK" },
            { get: { method: "JSONP" }}
            );
        zipCodes.get({}, function(zipCode){
            console.debug(zipCode.PostalCode);
        });
        console.debug(zipCodes.get());
        $scope.zipCodes = zipCodes.get().results;
```

Comment: `$scope.zipCodes = response;` should be changed to `$scope.zipCodes = response.data;`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `response.data` because while using `.then` you get all 4 parameter inside `response` object namely `data`, `status`, `headers`, `config`

```
$scope.zipCodes = response.data;
```

**Alternative**

You could do use `success` or `error` function

```
$http.get('http://api.geosvc.com/rest/US/84606/nearby?apikey=485a35b6b9544134b70af52867292071&d=20&pt=PostalCode&format=json')
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     $scope.zipCodes = data;
})
.error(function(error, status, headers, config) {
     console.log(status);
     console.log("Error occured");
});
```

Comment: Ok, it's logging an error, i'm not sure why because the url is valid json

Comment: "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://api.geosvc.com/rest/US/84606/nearby?apikey=485a35b6b9544134b70af52867292071&d=20&pt=PostalCode&format=json"

Comment: @Jordash that what I was afraid of..that is CORS issue..you need to implement `jsonp` on server side

Comment: Ok it's not returning that error anymore, that was from a bad API key, now it's just logging an error, but not giving any reason.

Comment: which error its logging..it should show it in console//

Comment: `Error occured` is what it's saying, from the `console.log`, also here is the updated API key `4ff687893a7b468cb520b3c4e967c4da`

Comment: @Jordash you should have check what is error status by putting debugger in code

Comment: The status is displaying `0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77261/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-jordash).

Answer (score 0):

what is the filter json doing there?. if you hit the url what you get is the array of elements. Just try printing

```
<pre>zipCodes {{zipCodes}}</pre>
```

and then if you want to print anything else you can iterate over it using ng-repeat and display it as you need.